# How can I programatically get a Telegram Bot's info

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

As per the Telegram Bot API's documentation I see it is possible to retrieve a bot's name (using `getMe`).

It is also possible to retrieve a `botpic` of a specific bot (using `getUserProfilePhotos`).

I've read Telegram's documentation again and again and I cannot find a way to obtain either of a Telegram bot's `Description`, `About` or `Commands`.

Also I cannot find any way to check what a specific bot's `allow groups`, `group privacy` and `domain` are set to.

Are Telegram Bots in some alpha/experimental state ?

It's a powerful idea but I see they lack most of the features you (as a developer) would expect them to have.

I see there are a lot of random features instead.

**How could I retrieve the upper properties (Description, About, Commands) for a specific bot using the Telegram Bot API ?**

**How could I retrieve a specific bot owner account's info, phone number Telegram Bot API ?**

P.S: I have all the tokens of the bots I am about to retrieve the upper information for.

Answer (score 2):

You can't with the bots API but it will be possible with userbot (a bot running as regular telegram account) using client API.

Obtaining number and information of the bot owner would be leaking of private data, privacy...